# Data persisting between connections on a Node/Express API

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building a Node/Express API front-end to a MongoDB and it all works fine for a single connection, but not with 2 or more.

If I make a call to the API with 2 connections at the same time, then the data within the called function becomes corrupted. Extract of code:

```
// This is the Express entry point
app.get('/user', async (request, response) => {
    const readResp = await read(request)
    response.send(readResp)
})


// The called function
async function read(request) {
    //
    try {

        // This gets data from MongoDB via Mongoose
        var connections = await Connection.find() 

        // Do other stuff here with connections,
        // but part-way through the connections 
        // variable gets corrupted as the new request has come in

        return { error: { code: 0, message: 'OK' }, connections: connections }
    } catch (error) {
        Log.errorToConsoleAndClose(error)
    }
}
```

I use express to wait for an incoming request, fire the `read()` function and return the response.

The problem comes when the 2nd request comes in at the same time, as it doesn't seem to use a new instance of `read()` and instead my code fails at some point as the var `connections` gets reset by the new incoming request.

Any clues/help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there's a straight-forward or common mistake here, but your example is abstracted so much it's hard to see what the problem could be. Your manipulateData not taking any arguments or returning anything suggests that you're operating on global data. I would be curious to see the body of this function

Comment: But yea please share something that can be used to reproduce your problem

Comment: I've changed the code from sudo to actual.

Comment: So based on your new description you're saying that the corruption is happening somewhere in the area you've commented and didn't share. There's nothing here that creates global state and create this kind of corruption, so that suggests that the problem is happening in the part of the code that you didn't share. (also it's pseudo, not sudo ;))

Answer (score 0):

I came across something similar with other data bases using async

The solution was to create the connection outside of the async request so that is keeps it open and then send multiple queries through .

what is happening is every time the the async is called its resetting the connection and not completing the request

One of the solutions was using **.then** or **promises**

Here is an example of using promises.

```
  router.post('/api/get_data', (req, res, next) => {
  try {
  MongoClient.connect(connectionStr, mongoOptions, function(err, client) {
   assert.equal(null, err);
   const db = client.db('db');

   //Step 1: declare promise

   var myPromise = () => {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        db
         .collection('your_collection')
         .find({id: 123})
         .limit(1)
         .toArray(function(err, data) {
             err 
                ? reject(err) 
                : resolve(data[0]);
           });
     });
   };

   //Step 2: async promise handler
   var callMyPromise = async () => {

      var result = await (myPromise());
      //anything here is executed after result is resolved
      return result;
   };

   //Step 3: make the call
   callMyPromise().then(function(result) {
      client.close();
      res.json(result);
   });
 }); //end mongo client


 } catch (e) {
  next(e)
 }
});
module.exports = router;
```

More info on the topic can be found at [Async MongoDB](https://medium.com/@rossbulat/using-promises-async-await-with-mongodb-613ed8243900)

Comment: Makes sense thanks Jono. I’ll take a look at my connection.